# Understanding Android ActivityLifeCyleCallbacks

Tags: android, cordova, android-lifecycle

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) for this class is somewhat confusing.  From what I have understood thus far I have concluded that

- The `OnResume/OnPause` pair of events occur when the activity starts/stops being available for **interaction** by the user.
- The `OnStart/OnStop` pair of events occur when the activity starts/stops being visible.  `Visible != Foreground` since the latter implies interactivity.

If this understanding is correct then it strikes me that the event names are rather wanting.  `OnStart/OnStop` would have been better off being called `OnVisible/OnInVisible`.  `OnResume/OnPause` would have been better off being called `OnInteractive/OnPassive`.

How does this tie in to the Window.OnPause/OnResume methods available in a Cordova application?  My assumption is that they map on to the corresponding Android activity lifecycle events.

Based on this understanding I am assuming that

- Broadcast Receivers
- Geolocation foreground/background mode switches are better done from the activity lifecycle OnStart/OnStop  events rather than the OnResume/OnPause events
- Data held in memory should be stashed away to a file/written to a DB etc on OnPause to reduce the application's memory footprint since if the application is not interactive those data are unlikely to be used anyway.

I used this understanding to create the following class as part of my custom Cordova plugin

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StateMonitor implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks 
{
 public static int isVisible = 0;
 public static int isInFG = 0;

 public static boolean isAppInForeground()
 {Feedback.postBackInfo("In FG:" + isInFG);return isInFG > 0;}

 public static boolean isAppVisible(){return isVisible > 0;}

 public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity,Bundle bundle){}

 public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity){}

 public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity)
 {
  isInFG++;
  Feedback.postBackInfo("Resumed:" + isInFG);
 }

 public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity)
 {
  isInFG--;
  Feedback.postBackInfo("Paused");
 }

 public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity,Bundle outState)
 {}

 public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity)
 {Feedback.postBackInfo("started");isVisible++;}

 public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity){isVisible--;}
}
```

I start monitoring for activity lifecycle events by issuing a

```
cordova.getActivity().getApplication().
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new StateMonitor());
```

where `Feedback` is a helper class I use internally in the plugin to do things such as post back messages to my server for logging and display in real time in my web browser.

from the

```
public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView)
```

method of the plugin.  This immediately throws up a problem:

- These events do not start firing when I first start the application
- My guess her is that calling `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` is "too late" to monitor the initial OnStart/OnResume events since by that time that call is made - from `Plugin.initialize` - those events have "already occurred".

What things can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found I could make it work is by adding this class inside of MainActivity in Cordova app. It would be outside of your plugin. 
Nothing else worked.

Comment: Could you explain how you went about adding the class - by hacking the relevant Java code or at run time via JS...?

Comment: Yes, hacked a Java class. ActivityLifecycleCallbacks was added in API 14, Ice Cream. My guess was that cordova.getActivity().getApplication() will bring you an "older" version of that object.